# JavaScript: How to correctly handle content break in contenteditable when user hits enter and caret is within html nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, range, contenteditable, caret

I'm working on a simple block editor system and I'm struggling on moving / styling the content between blocks when the user hits enter in the middle of it.
Let's say I have this editable div, with the caret being shown as "|" below:

```
<p contenteditable="true">this is my <strong><em>content |with</em> some styles</strong></p>
```

If I hit enter, I want to achieve this:

```
<p contenteditable="true">this is my <strong><em>content </em></strong></p>
<p contenteditable="true"><strong><em>with</em> some styles</strong></p>
```

More precisely, I'm already handling the node creation (`p` tags above on enter key for instance).

Where I'm struggling is with the content itself when user hits enter and that the cursor is within html nodes. Here, the caret is positioned within a `strong` and `em` nodes. I find it really hard to (1) determine its exact position if there are multiple HTML child nodes involved like above and (2) split the inner content accordingly ("this is my content with some styles") and reassigning the `<strong>` and `<em>` tags where they are logically supposed to be on both lines.

Also, having multiple `contenteditable` elements is on purpose and a current constraint.

Would greatly appreciate some guidance on this in pure JavaScript. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is having the same issue, here's how I solved it:

```
// START: Somewhere in my code
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper') // Content wrapper
wrapper.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)

const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) { // User hits enter
    e.preventDefault() // cancel enter
    // ... other logic
    splitContent(e.target) // call my method to split content if required
  }
}
// END: Somewhere in my code

// the method that solved my issue, using Range and Selection objects
const splitContent = (node) => {
  const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
  // Select the end node and its offset from the caret
  range.setStart(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
  // End the selected range at the end of the node content 
  range.setEnd(node, node.childNodes.length) 
  // Extract content from the defined range (the key is here)
  const content = range.extractContents() 
  // Call another method to use this extracted content with formatting intact
  doWhateverWithTheExtractedContent(content)
}
```